# How do I say "until" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, prepositions

The difference that I am looking for is one that I use in German like this: *bis einschließlich Freitag* — "until, including, Friday". 
How is this handled in Esperanto? *Until* in English can be a bit imprecise — "until **including** Friday" or "until, but **not including** Friday".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, *ĝis* means a a period of time up to, but not surpassing an event:

> Punkton de la spaco aŭ de la tempo, aŭ mezuron, kiun la ago atingas, sed ne transpasas aŭ preterpasas.

You may be looking for *tra*, or *through*:

> Tempon, dum kiu daŭras iu ago, ekde ĝia komenciĝo.

"A time during which something continues some action, since its beginning."

So in your example, you can say *mi restas ĝis vendredo* to mean "I stay until and **not including** Friday." Or, *mi restas tra vendredo* to mean "I stay **through** Friday." Which isn't precisely the same as **until and including** but it's really close.

- http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/%C4%9Dis
- http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/tra

Comment: That's really cool! Thank you. I don't think I have thought of "tra" this way before.

Answer (score 7):

From Vortaro (among other definitons of the word):

***ĝis*** 
*Prep., montranta la punkton, kiun la ago atingas, sed ne trans- aŭ preter-pasas* 
Preposition showing the point which an action attains, **but not beyond**.

Examples:

- Snow hides only until spring. 
  *neĝo kaŝas nur ĝis printempo.*
- He sees only until the end of his nose. 
  *li vidas nur ĝis la pinto de sia nazo.*
- She cried from morning until evening. 
  *ŝi ploradas de mateno ĝis vespero*

Comment: Cool! Thank you! Could you extend your answer for how to say "gxis" including Friday? Good to know that the standard is not including the event.

Comment: *Ĝis* often does include the endpoint; to specify, say *ĝis vendredo inkluzive/ekskluzive* or *inklude/eksklude*.

Comment: Uh-oh. So Esperanto does have the same possible confusion. Well, good to know! Dankon.

Answer (score 5):

"Ĝis" is a preposition like "until" that's used in just about the same way, and as far as I know, it *does not* include the second thing mentioned like you want it to. Something worth noting is that unlike "until", "ĝis" is also a casual way of saying goodbye.

Comment: Casual: _ĝis/ĝis la_ -- Formal: _ĝis la revido_.

Answer (score 3):

According to PMEG the [prepositional *ĝis* **includes**](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/direktaj_rolvortetoj/ghis.html#i-3vs) the end time. Some examples:

- *Mi laboras ĉiutage de frua mateno ĝis malfrua vespero* : I work at the late evening but not past it, i.e. not at night.
- *Ili trinkis ĝis malfrue en la nokto* : They stopped drinking before dawn.

Therefore

- *Mi restas ĝis vendredo* : I am still here on Friday, but I will leave before Saturday.

If you want to **exclude** the end time, you can use *antaŭ*:

- *Ĝi devas esti preta antaŭ sabato* : It must be ready before/done by Saturday.

PMEG emphasises, that even [in case of an interval *ĝis* **includes**](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/direktaj_rolvortetoj/ghis.html#i-mav) the end point.

- *Ili loĝas en apartamentoj 101 ĝis 150* : They also live in the apartment no. 150.

If you need to emphasise, that the end point of the interval is included or excluded, say it:

- *Ili loĝas en apartamentoj 101 ĝis 150 inkluzive/ekskluzive.*

However in practice the need for excluding an end point is scant elsewhere than in mathematics and computer science, where one uses different expressions altogether.